# PushModalAsync not working correctly after call back activity is fired

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

1. Tabbed page is the root and there is "Account" content page as navigation page inside it.
2. Account page has `OnAppearing` event.
3. On a button click in Account page, a modal popup "Login" content page is pushed.
4. In Login page, user will be authenticated and callback url is called and another modal page, Page1, is pushed. <----Issue is the `OnAppearing` event (step 2) of Account page is called. It did not get called at step 3.

```
var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
    new Uri($"mywebsite.com/auth/" + scheme),
    new Uri("myapp://auth#"));
                     
await ((MainPage)Application.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1());
```

5. Further another issue is when both the modals are closed using `PopModalAsync()` in Page 1, the `OnAppearing` event of Account page is not called again.

```
int count = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count;
for (int currModal = 0; currModal < count; currModal++)
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync(false);
}
```

6. To debug the cause, pushed modal async before and after callback activity, and found that it is causing the issue.

```
// OnAppearing of Account page not getting called
await ((MainPage)Application.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1());

var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
    new Uri($"mywebsite.com/auth/" + scheme),
    new Uri("myapp://auth#"));

// ISSUE: OnAppearing of Account page getting called here
await ((MainPage)Application.Current.MainPage).CurrentPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1());
```

7. Below is the callback activity

```
[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
DataScheme = "myapp",
DataHost = "auth")]
public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
{
}
```

This behavior is in Android, did not test on iOS.

Comment: This has been an open issue since 2018 when using `TabbedPage` on the Android platform: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3855 (Lots of details and possible workarounds(?) so worth the time to read it all)

Comment: I have gone through this thread, my issue is not with tabbed pages "OnAppearing" events. It is more to do with Modals within a navigation page after call back activity. All seems to work fine if there is no call back activity.

Comment: How do you use the callback activity? Does this callback activity to be necessary？

Comment: Call back activity is used for authentication, it is necessary since it calls the server side code to authenticate the user.

Comment: keep on searching. If i have something new, i would feedback ASAP.

Comment: For now, I replaced Modal page with Navigation Page and hide the tabs.